# Using a bastion server: how to model an emergency entrance?

Tags: firewalls, ssh

I have set up a bastion server (A) that acts as the only "hallway" to enter a bunch of other private VPS's (B). That is to say: the private machines only accept SSH-connections from (A) on a non-standard port, which is a hard firewall rule, and only accept these connections from (A) using a specific user and a specific key.

I was wondering which strategy I should use for emergencies where for instance the bastion (A) goes down, gets compromised or in somehow gets useless. It would make my private VPS's (B) inaccessible for ever.

Should I allow for the (B) machines to be accessed through another IP address than the bastion (A) as well? I don't have the infrastructure to allocate whole IP blocks, so permissions based on ranges won't work for me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This isn't a security question. Why not simply replace/rebuild A when it goes down? Why not access the VPS's through their control panel? There appear to be a bunch of factors that you have not disclosed.

Comment: I seriously hope control panels don't override firewall rules and `PasswordAuthentication no`...

Comment: if they log in locally, they sure do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an expansion of what @schroeder said in the comments.  You can access (A) or any of (B)'s *without SSH* if you are using a decent provider.

Most VPS services allow a console login.  The console login is not performed through `ssh` but through a `getty` (or `agetty`, `mgetty` or other variant) process talking to the virtualisation supervisor.

As an example that I often use (and so do most VPS services), the KVM `virt-manager` has a `virsh console` command.  Then the VPS provider only needs to pipe input and output of that process into the web/app console.  The

> PasswordAuthentication no

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is never used by that method since the `sshd` process is not being touched.

As for the security considerations of this method, they're in your VPS provider court.  Most providers provide a pretty decent set of checks before you can login into the console (linode, digital ocean and AWS are three that I did use the console and I could configure dual factor auth).  That said, this is simply analogous to going into a server room and connecting a physical console to the console port of your machine.